Extract data from coinmarketcap api http get response with power automate cloud flow
The api returns data in a json object but it has an unusual structure. For example if returning bitcoin data I get this:
        "data": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Bitcoin",
                "symbol": "BTC",
                "slug": "bitcoin",
etc...

and I get this for ethereum:
        "data": {
            "1027": {
                "id": 1027,
                "name": "Ethereum",
                "symbol": "ETH",
                "slug": "ethereum",
etc...

When I use Parse JSON action with the bitcoin sample data it returns this schema:
        "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "1": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "symbol": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "slug": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
etc...

That works fine for bitcoin but will not work for ethereum due to the "1" in the schema, which would have to be "1027". Is there any way to get rid of the "1" or make it dynamic with a variable?
I have tried to use a variable for the UCID (universal coin ID) but power automate throws errors. I found a video on youtube where somebody did exactly what I am trying to do but he misses out some steps which I could not get to work. Here is the video: text

This question is similar to: How to loop through a JSON with dynamic properties in Power Automate. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
